# When I turn on my PC it starts Windows giving me no choice to use Linux or Windows

Tags: dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu on my PC alongside Windows 10 with a USB key. When I turn on my PC it starts Windows; it gives me no choice to use Linux or Windows. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this process:

- Boot into Windows OS
- Combine `Windows` + `r` keys together and type `cmd` to open command prompt.
- On command prompt type `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` and hit `Enter` key

Once done, you will start getting Grub menu every time you boot your laptop.

P.S : To get dual boot working fine on my dell laptop, I took help of this link [dual boot windows and ubuntu](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/) and I followed above steps too for setting up the grub menu and both OS are working fine on my laptop.